# Adding another social media icon to wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to modifying php files in wordpress. I need to add another social media icon (houzz) to my header that is not included in the template. I have found the correct file and the code but I cannot seem to get houzz to show. Any help is greatly appreciated. here is the code:

```
<?php 
                if( has_nav_menu( 'social-menu' ) ){

                    // #social-menu
                    mfn_wp_social_menu();

                } else {

                    $target = mfn_opts_get('social-target') ? 'target="_blank"' : false;

                    echo '<ul class="social">';

                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-skype') ) echo '<li class="skype"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-skype') .'" title="Skype"><i class="icon-skype"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-facebook') ) echo '<li class="facebook"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-facebook') .'" title="Facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-googleplus') ) echo '<li class="googleplus"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-googleplus') .'" title="Google+"><i class="icon-gplus"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-twitter') ) echo '<li class="twitter"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-twitter') .'" title="Twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-vimeo') ) echo '<li class="vimeo"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-vimeo') .'" title="Vimeo"><i class="icon-vimeo"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-youtube') ) echo '<li class="youtube"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-youtube') .'" title="YouTube"><i class="icon-play"></i></a></li>';                      
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-flickr') ) echo '<li class="flickr"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-flickr') .'" title="Flickr"><i class="icon-flickr"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-linkedin') ) echo '<li class="linkedin"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-linkedin') .'" title="LinkedIn"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-pinterest') ) echo '<li class="pinterest"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-pinterest') .'" title="Pinterest"><i class="icon-pinterest"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-dribbble') ) echo '<li class="dribbble"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-dribbble') .'" title="Dribbble"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-instagram') ) echo '<li class="instagram"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-instagram') .'" title="Instagram"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-behance') ) echo '<li class="behance"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-behance') .'" title="Behance"><i class="icon-behance"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-vkontakte') ) echo '<li class="vkontakte"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-vkontakte') .'" title="VKontakte"><i class="icon-vkontakte"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-viadeo') ) echo '<li class="viadeo"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-viadeo') .'" title="Viadeo"><i class="icon-viadeo"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-xing') ) echo '<li class="xing"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-xing') .'" title="Xing"><i class="icon-xing"></i></a></li>';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-rss') ) echo '<li class="rss"><a '.$target.' href="'. get_bloginfo('rss2_url') .'" title="RSS"><i class="icon-rss"></i></a></li>';
                    echo '</ul>';

                }
            ?>
```

Comment: First you need to figure out which section of code is being run. Do you know if the `if` or the `else` block is being run?

Comment: I think it's if. The page is only showing icons that have links entered in the back end of wordpress.

Comment: Is this website live? Does it matter if you mess it up temporarily to figure this out?

Comment: ok, add `die('test');` to the if block. This should display 'test' on a white screen if the if block is being executed.

Comment: Now try adding it to the else block.

Comment: is there no way to just remove the php and put in a an icon list that can only be manually updated?

Comment: Shall I do that for you?

Comment: can you do that without access to the back end of wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

**Create A Child Theme**

First things first. When editing theme files its always best to use a child theme.

From the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

> A child theme is a theme that inherits the functionality and styling
>   of another theme, called the parent theme. Child themes are the
>   recommended way of modifying an existing theme.

Once you've created and activated your child theme you can copy the template you need to edit into your child theme (keep the folder structure of your theme if the template files is not in the root of your theme)

**Editing your template file**

Since the `mfn_opts_get('social-houzz')` option does not exist you'll need to just insert the html you want to add for your social icon like so.

```
<?php 
    if( has_nav_menu( 'social-menu' ) ){

        // #social-menu
        mfn_wp_social_menu();

    } else {

        $target = mfn_opts_get('social-target') ? 'target="_blank"' : false;

        echo '<ul class="social">';

            if( mfn_opts_get('social-skype') ) echo '<li class="skype"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-skype') .'" title="Skype"><i class="icon-skype"></i></a></li>';
            // Other social icons

            // Your custom icon.
            echo '<li class="houzz"><a '.$target.' href="link_to_houzz" title="Houzz"><i class="icon-houzz"></i></a></li>';

        echo '</ul>';

    }
?>
```

**Add CSS**

Now that you have a `li` with the class houzz you'll need to add CSS for it. This should also be done in the child theme and not the main theme's stylesheet. Look in your theme's stylesheet for one of the other social icons and copy the css for it (`li.skype` for example) to your child theme's stylesheet. Then replace "skype" with houzz. You'll also need to edit your new `icon-houzz` class with a new icon or the skype icon will be used.

**Note:** If you provide a link to the theme you're using I could provide more specific instructions. My instructions were written going solely off the code sample you provided.

Comment: Hope that works for you. It should if the code snippet you posted is the code creating the icons. If not we'll have to look closer at your theme to figure out where to make changes.

Comment: I'm using http://themes.muffingroup.com/be/interior/. I'm having trouble finding the icon classes to modify one for houzz.

Comment: It looks like their in `mfn-icons.css`. Your theme uses an icon font which makes things tricker. Here is the skype css `.icon-skype:before { content: '\e90d'; }` You'll need to either pick an icon from the theme, use your own icon font for the houzz icon, or use a ping. If you use a ping you'll want to make it black and then set it to 50% opacity. Then remove the opacity on hover. That way it will match the other icons

Comment: Would it be possible to use an image for the houzz icon?

Comment: Yes, you could use png as a background image.

Comment: I tried overwriting the Php file and support has said it wont work. they said  

"if you know coding, then you can play with includes/header-top-area.php file because that's the only way to use own icons in header." I'm not 100% sure what they are referring to here.

Comment: If you're using Wordpress the technique I mentioned in my post should work just fine. You should never modify/change core Wordpress or theme files if at all possible.

Comment: I created a child theme, I took the template file that I needed, modified it and saved it to the child theme folder. Then I uploaded the child theme and activated it. Nothing happened. Looks to have the same file structure as the parent theme as well... I asked Be themes Support about it and they responded "No, you can't save this file in child theme folder because this won't work." I'm not sure what I'm missing but I will keep digging around. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you can't use a child theme then they didn't code their theme correctly. If thats the case you might just have to modify the original. But be sure to backup your changes before updating the theme or your changes will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice and I'm not recommending you do this but this is *an* answer that just removes the PHP and replaces it with pure HTML. You now need to add in the appropriate `href` values and ensure you style the houz icon using CSS. This method will break any content management functionality and you will only be able to update this part of the header manually.

```
<ul class="social">
    <li class="facebook"><a href=""><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <!-- add more icons here... -->
    <!-- your custom icon below -->
    <li class="houz"><a href=""><i class="icon-houz"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Matty! I will try this if I can't get the other one going. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem : ) let me know if you need any more help, @Craig Harshbarger's answer is what you should be doing if possible and will allow you to update the theme in the future and keep the content management functionality.